# Binding NSArrayController to moc in NSPersistentDocument subclass in Xcode4 in XIB view

Tags: xcode4, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentdocument

I have my subclass of NSPersistentDocument who's superclass has [self managedObjectContext]

Trying to set the bindings of my NSArrayController in the xib. When I set the Parameter's Moc, the bind to choices are: File's Owner, App, and Prefs. (The NSArrayController's entity is set to the Entity name in my context)

Model KeyPath defaults to self.
I then bind the value of a table column to the NSArrayController (Which I'm not sure how to rename under Xcode 4).arrangedObjects.(name of my entity property)

There's a populate button on the UI to self populate the context.

When I run. The UI won't come up and all I get in the console is repeated:
-[MyDoc persistentStoreCoordinator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10015adf0

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have bound the managedObjectContext directly to the NSPersistentDocument.  What you probably need to do is in the bindings panel bind to the Files Owner (assuming this is NSPersistentDocument) and then set the binding path (Model Key Path) to managedObjectContext.